# The Fundamental Homomorphism Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

The Fundamental Homomorphism Theorem states that:

Let R, R'
be rings,
ϕ : R → R'
a homomorphism. Then with K = kerϕ, there is an isomorphism
between R/K and ϕ(R).

However in some example questions i have seen, they prove that the function is not only a homomorphism but surjective also. Is proving surjectivity also necessary for this theorem?

Comment: Surjectivity allows you to replace $\phi\left(R\right)$ by $R^{\prime}$ (which is probably what they do in said examples).